# How to unit test to the case where there are two public methods, one calling another?

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, mockito

What is the way to test the methods when there are two public methods and a method calls another public method in the same class?

How should I write unit tests in this scenario?

---

An example

```
class SpecificIntMath {
   public int add(int a,int b) {
       return a+b;
   }
   public int multiply(int a, int b) {
       int mul = 0;
       for(int i = 0;i<b,i++) {
           mul=add(a,mul);
       }
       return mul;
   }
}
```

This example doesn't show the complexity of both the methods involved but the concept.

Should I test `add` and `multiply` separately? If I should test `multiply` only, I feel like we miss out cases where `multiple` cannot provide parameters.

Assuming `multiply` and `add` to be tested separately, should I be able to mock `add`? How is that possible?

Assuming `multiply` and `add` to be tested separately and  I shouldn't mock, should I let `add` perform as it is. If this is the case how should I deal with the flow of the program inside `add`?

What is the approach to test such a kind of situation.

---

Edit 1:

In the below code,

```
class MCVC {
    public boolean getWhereFrom(List<User> users) {
        boolean allDone = true;
        for(User user: users){
            String url = user.getUrl();
            switch(url) {
                case Consts.GOOGLE:
                    someDao.updateFromAddr(user);
                    user.setEntry("Search Engine");
                    break;
                case Consts.FACEBOOK:
                    someDao.updateFromAddr(user);
                    user.setEntry("Social Media");
                    break;
                case Consts.HOME:
                    someDao.updateToAddr(user);
                    user.setEntry("Company");
                default
                    user.setEntry(null);
                    allDone = false;
                    break;
            }
        }
        return allDone;
    }

    public void likedDeck() {
        List<Users> usersList = deckDao.getPotentialUsers(345L,HttpStatus.OK);
        boolean flag = getWhereFrom(usersList);

        if(flag) {
            for(User user: usersList) {
                //some Action
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Should I consider `getWhereFrom()` while testing `likedDeck()` or should I assume any default situation? If I consider default situation, I lose out on cases where the output isn't default. I am not sure I should mock it since class which is calling is being tested. [Spying/Mocking class under test](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19269623/4669984)

Comment: Just test them seperately.  Donot try to mock `add` when testing `multiply`, you don't even know if `multiply` will call `add` (atleast you are not supposed to know that when writing the test).

Comment: Also note that your multiply is broken when b < 0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't care.

You use unit-testing to test the **contract** of *each* public method on its own. Thus you write tests that make sure that both `add()` and `multiply()` do what they are supposed to do.

The fact that the one uses the other internally is of no interest on the outside. Your tests should neither know nor care about this internal implementation detail.

And just for the record: as your code is written right now; you absolutely do not turn to *mocking* here. Mocking is not required here; and only **adds** the risk of testing something that has *nothing* to do with your real production code. You **only** use mocking for situations when you have to control aspects of objects in order to enable testing. But nothing in your example code needs mocking to be tested. And if it would - it would be an indication of poor design/implementation (given the contract of those methods)!

Edit; given the changes example in the question:

First of all, there is a **bug** in `getWhereFrom()` - you iterate a *list*; but you keep overwriting the return value in that list. So when the first iteration sets the result to false; that information might be lost in the next loop.

I see two options for the actual question:

- You turn to Mockito; and its "spy" concept to do partial mocking; in case you want to keep your source code as is
- Me, personally; I would rather invest time into improving the production code. It looks to me as `getWhereFrom()` could be worth its *own* class (where I would probably not have it work on a **list** of users; but just **one** user; that also helps with returning a single boolean value ;-). And when you do that, you can use dependency injection to acquire a (mocked) instance of that "WhereFromService" class.

In other words: the code you are showing could be reworked/refactored; for example to more clearly follow the [SRP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle). But that is of course a larger undertaking; that you need to discuss with the people around you.

Comment: Okay, If I test both separately, then how do I manipulate data inside `multiply` [In my case I have to mock certain `Dao`] the output of which directly affects the internals of `add`?

Comment: I have used DI to push the mock. The problem is that the output of the Dao is a list and the "`add`" method has a `switch-case` and more `Dao` which affect some state and I have to test their arguments. Every Mock is Dependency Injected.

Comment: Cleared the bug.

Answer (score 0):

At least test them both seperatly. That the multiply test implicitly tests the add is no problem. In most of this cases you should ask yourself the question if it is necessary that both methods need to be public.

Answer (score 0):

> Should I test add and multiply separately?

You should test them separately, if you are doing unit testing. You would only like to test them together when doing component or integration tests.

> Assuming multiply and add to be tested separately, should I be able to
>   mock add?

yes

> How is that possible?

use mockito or any other mocking framework. Exactly how you can see here [Use Mockito to mock some methods but not others](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14970516/use-mockito-to-mock-some-methods-but-not-others)

> Assuming multiply and add to be tested separately and I shouldn't
>   mock, should I let add perform as it is.

I wouldn't do that. Internal changes in add could affect the tests from multiply and your tests would get more complicated and unstable.